# how to send authorization header data inside Streamed request (send) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, httprequest

how to send authorization header data  inside Streamed request (send) in Flutter:
i need to add `HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $_apiToken'` to the request headers

```
try {
    final client = new http.Client();
    final streamedRest = await client.send(http.Request('get', uri));

    return streamedRest.stream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(json.decoder)
        .map((data) => Helper.getData(data))
        .expand((data) => (data as List))
        .map((data) => Category.fromJSON(data));
  } catch (e) {
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: uri.toString()).toString());
    return new Stream.value(new Category.fromJSON({}));
  }
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    final client = new http.Client();
    final streamedRest = await client.get(url, // Your API endpoint
          headers: {
            'authorization': "Token $_Token"
          });
    return streamedRest.stream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(json.decoder)
        .map((data) => Helper.getData(data))
        .expand((data) => (data as List))
        .map((data) => Category.fromJSON(data));
  } catch (e) {
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: uri.toString()).toString());
    return new Stream.value(new Category.fromJSON({}));
  }
```

please try like this.